# Autoplaying of video in player-fullscreen rather than background fullscreen using HTML5 and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I want to autoplay video in fullscreen. I searched and found out that Fullscreen API can be used to do this and found out that code similar to this can be used.

```
viewFullScreen.addEventListener("click", function () {
    var docElm = document.documentElement;
    if (docElm.requestFullscreen) {
        docElm.requestFullscreen();
    }
    else if (docElm.msRequestFullscreen) {
        docElm.msRequestFullscreen();
    }
    else if (docElm.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        docElm.mozRequestFullScreen();
    }
    else if (docElm.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
        docElm.webkitRequestFullScreen();
    }
}, false);
```

This code works fine. But this will need some triggering event like mouse click or some keyboard input. But is it possible playing a video automatically in fullscreen without any triggering event as soon as the html file is opened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode#When_a_fullscreen_request_fails):

> NOTE: Fullscreen requests need to be called from within an event handler or otherwise they will be denied.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out!! Ironically I missed out reading "notes" from that page.